# Why are there out-of-date tower frequencies on the VFR sectional chart, without a NOTAM?

Tags: visual-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts

I flew today to Salinas, CA and had a little trouble reaching Salinas tower (KSNS). The current VFR sectional shows the tower frequency as 119.4. However, apparently the frequency changed to 119.525 on June 2014 (according to http://www.montereybay99s.org/newsletter/July2014issue.pdf)

The current VFR sectional was issued in August 2014, after the frequency change. I'm wondering why (a) the frequency is incorrectly printed on the current VFR sectional, and (b) if it's an error why there is no NOTAM about it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not a printing error. FAA sectional charts are updated only once every six months. In order to to reduce the number of NOTAMs due to sectional changes (which can number in the hundreds between cycles), the FAA provides a section in the **Airport Facility Directory** (AFD), titled "Aeronautical Chart Bulletin" that identifies changes that have occurred since a chart's publication. Pilots should check this section on each AFD update for changes on their intended route of flight. Once the change is posted in the AFD, the respective NOTAM is taken down.

Here is an image of the applicable AFD page for Salinas, as of the date of this answer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. It's surprising though that the sectional which became active 2 months after the change occurred didn't have the update. You'd think there would've been enough planning time ahead of the freq change to make sure it gets into the next sectional.

Comment: @Nils The final image of the chart needs to be ready for print in advance of its release date to allow time to make up the physical copies (and the digital images are identical to the physical ones for obvious reasons: You don't want two people with "the same" sectional to be seeing different data). Of course if the next update cycle doesn't have the correct frequency on it that *would* be an error, [and should be reported](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/faq/?print=go#q6a) so the AeroNav folks can fix it.

Comment: do apps like Foreflight include the Aeronautical Chart Bulletin changes?

Comment: @rbp I had the same question. On foreflight you can get it in the "southwest a/fd supplemental" in documents tab, faa section. But the actual map in foreflight matches the paper sectional, which is out of date.